# express post method not working with Content-Type:multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, express, routes, body-parser

After search all i got tired
can anyone tell me why post method not working when i add Content-Type:multipart/form-data in postman.Note without adding this suck everything works fine. here is my app.js

```
var app = express();
var apiRoutes = require('./routes/apiRoutes');
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded([{extended: false}, {limit: '50mb'}]));
app.use(cookieParser());   
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
app.use(multipart());;
app.use(apiRoutes)
```

here is my apiRoutes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fn = require('../webservices');
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty')();
router.post('/api/login', fn.test);
module.exports = router;
```

and here is my webservices.js

```
function test(req,res){
    console.log("hello there");
}
module.exports = {
test
}
```

and this show error

TypeError: this[("visit" + node.type)] is not a function

Please report this entire error and stack trace to https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues
   at Object.visitNode (/home/ais/Acruss-NodeJs/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:225:37)
   at Object.visit (/home/ais/Acruss-NodeJs/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:212:10)
   at Object.visitBlock (/home/ais/Acruss-NodeJs/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:295:12)
   at Object.visitNode (/home/ais/Acruss-NodeJs/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:225:37)
   at Object.visit (/home/ais/Acruss-NodeJs/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:212:10)
   at Object.compile (/home/ais/Acruss-NodeJs/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:66:10)
   at parse (/home/ais/Acruss-NodeJs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:114:19)
   at Object.exports.compile (/home/ais/Acruss-NodeJs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:205:16)
   at handleTemplateCache (/home/ais/Acruss-NodeJs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:174:25)
   at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/ais/Acruss-NodeJs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:380:10)

Comment: why do you use multipart/form-data? do you want to upload any file?

Comment: Yes i  want file upload, also app developer give me this either when upload or without upload

Comment: when you use multipart/form-data you should use a express middlware to handle form-data I recommend you to use 'multer' module that is make it very easy to upload files...@shivshankar

Comment: I used but didn't work.

Comment: I think you want to upload file from client side like an application? or you want to upload from html form in website? @shivshankar

Comment: Humm.. I am using with android app

Comment: oops! multipart/form-data is a header for html form submiting not for uploading files from client side; your application must upload files with ftp protocol on specific directory on your server @shivshankar

Comment: How can i do it ?

Comment: which platform do you use for android app? @

Comment: I'll ask for android team i sure they are using api level 23 or 24

Comment: i can ask him to set header like postman so my code works  but Then how to set header ?

Answer (score 1):

so everything you need for using ftp is 
[here](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-start-ftp-android)

i recommend you to read this

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. But if there no file and I'd like to set header content-type multupart/form-data then how to  do this stuff in node.

Comment: this header means that you want to use special encoding type for your files that comes from client side so if you dont have any file you should not use this header @shivshankar